# Does stereo_proc undistort images?

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, image-pipeline

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have tried to use the image_pipeline stereo_image_proc to get the rectified images.
The question is, when stereo_image_proc produces image_rect images, should they be undistorted? Have a look at my screenshot:

[image: image description]

I have given the distortion matrix to the topic and I have tried to undistort the images myself and quite happy with it.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/318640/does-stereo_proc-undistort-images?/) by [EdwardNur](https://answers.ros.org/users/39496/edwardnur/) on ROS Answers with karma: 115 on 2019-03-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, it is written [here](http://wiki.ros.org/stereo_image_proc). Quote :

> stereo_image_proc performs the duties of image_proc for both cameras, **undistorting** and colorizing the raw images. Note that for properly calibrated stereo cameras, undistortion is actually combined with rectification, transforming the images so that their scanlines line up for fast stereo processing.

---

Originally posted by [tuandl](https://answers.ros.org/users/28760/tuandl/) with karma: 358 on 2019-03-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0